# Warnings on 'LOAD DATA INFILE' from .CSV - Integers and Dates

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, load, file-io

This is probably a pretty simple issue but for the life of me I don't see what I am missing when I try to import this CSV file into my SQL table.

I keep ending up with my int 'idRefs' with 0s, and my date 'dob' as all 12 31 1969

---

Examples of the warnings:

```
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '
10002' for column 'idRef' at row 1  |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'dob' at row 1
```

The LOAD DATA INFILE statement --

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/user/Documents/pplList.csv' INTO TABLE people 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES 
(idRef, lastName, firstName, dob, rsNum, slNum, firstVisit, pplPref, coachName);
```

Just some examples from the CSV --

```
idRef,lastName,firstName,dob,rsNum,slNum,firstAppt,pplPref,coachName"
10001,BlankA,NameA,4/15/68,1000000,4600000,3/31/08,Positive,John Jay"
10002,BlankB,NameB,10/28/78,1000001,4600001,8/19/11,Positive,John Jay"
```

The 'people' table SQL code --

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;
CREATE TABLE people
(
id   smallint unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
idRef   int unsigned NOT NULL,
lastName    varchar(255), 
firstName   varchar(255),
dob   date NOT NULL,
rsNum   int unsigned NOT NULL,
slNum   int unsigned NOT NULL,
firstAppt   date NOT NULL,
pplPref   varchar(255),
coachName   varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY   (id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

### `idRef`

I don't know why you chose to end your lines with a double-quote, but the `LINES TERMINATED BY '"'` option [does take care of that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

However, since you overrode the default line terminator, your *actual* newline characters are no longer considered to be anything more than data; consequently, there is a newline character at the start of each piece of `id` data.

This is actually evident in the warning.

I'd avoid the `"` altogether and use normal line endings, but the quick fix is:
`LINES TERMINATED BY '"\n'`.

### `dob`

The *date of birth* issue is a little different and I'm not sure about that one, but I'd consider storing dates in a standard format within your CSV file, as they are rather ambiguous right now.

Instead of `4/15/68`, try `1968-15-04`.

MySQL may be interpreting the two-year date `68` as `1968` (I would) and, though [the `DATE` column supports that year (and all other years going back to `1000`!)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), it may be choosing to apply further restrictions based on your weak input format.

> The `DATE` type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays `DATE` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format. The supported range is `'1000-01-01'` to `'9999-12-31'`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I borrowed that LINES TERMINATED BY '"' elsewhere and assumed that I then needed that character in the CSV file, which clearly I don't! I guess that '"' just means whitespace/line-return!

Comment: @user2573020: That was perfectly valid (if a little pointless), but you gave the terminator as `'"'` rather than `'"\n'` and, therefore, the _actual_ newline was considered to be part of your data... and consequently part of the ID, since it's the first token on each line.