# Only Some Dates From SQL SELECT Being Set To "0" or "1969-12-31" -- UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, date, select, unix-timestamp

So I have been doing pretty well on my project ([Link to previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596324/warnings-on-load-data-infile-from-csv-integers-and-dates)), and have managed to learn quite a bit, but there is this one problem that has been  *really* dogging me for days and I just can't seem to solve it.

It has to do with using the UNIX_TIMESTAMP call to convert dates in my SQL database to UNIX time-format, but for some reason only one set of dates in my table is giving me issues!

==============

So these are the values I am getting -

```
#abridged here, see the results from the SELECT statement below to see the rest
#of the fields outputted

| firstVst   | nextVst    | DOB       |
| 1206936000 | 1396238400 |         0 |
| 1313726400 | 1313726400 | 278395200 |
| 1318910400 | 1413604800 |         0 |
| 1319083200 | 1413777600 |         0 |
```

when I use this SELECT statment -

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(firstVst) AS firstVst,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(nextVst) AS nextVst, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DOB) AS DOB FROM people 
ORDER BY "ref DESC";
```

**So my big question is:** why in the heck are 3 out of 4 of my DOBs being set to date of 0 (IE 12/31/1969 on my PC)? Why is this not happening in my other fields?

---

I can see the data quite well using a more simple SELECT statement and the DOB field looks fine...?

```
#formatting broken to change some variable names etc.

select * FROM people;

| ref | lastName | firstName | DOB      | rN   | lN   | firstVst  | disp | repName        | nextVst   |
| 10001 | BlankA   | NameA     | 1968-04-15 | 1000000 | 4600000 | 2008-03-31 | Positive  | Patrick Smith | 2014-03-31 |
| 10002 | BlankB   | NameB     | 1978-10-28 | 1000001 | 4600001 | 2011-08-19 | Positive  | Patrick Smith | 2011-08-19 |
| 10003 | BlankC   | NameC     | 1941-06-08 | 1000002 | 4600002 | 2011-10-18 | Positive  | Patrick Smith | 2014-10-18 |
| 10004 | BlankD   | NameD     | 1952-08-01 | 1000003 | 4600003 | 2011-10-20 | Positive  | Patrick Smith | 2014-10-20 |
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because those DoB's are from before 12/31/1969, and the UNIX epoch starts then, so anything prior to that would be negative.

From Wikipedia:

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds.

A bit more elaboration: Basically what you're trying to do isn't possible. Depending on what it's for, there may be a different way you can do this, but using UNIX timestamps probably isn't the best idea for dates like that.

Comment: Wow, I certainly hadn't thought of that. Pretty early for the beginning of time! After getting rid of the UNIX_TIMESTAMP call I can see the 'years' of my dates but nothing else.

Comment: Huh? Even though with `SELECT *` they're showing the whole date? How come you want it in a UNIX timestamp format anyway?

Comment: I am storing the dates in an object and then calling them with ++echo <?php echo date('m d Y',$person->nextVst)?>;++ But without the UNIX_TIMESTAMP in the SQL statement I get junk

Comment: I see. have you tried `echo date('m d Y', strtotime($person->nextVst));`? It should work for any date after Fri, 13 Dec 1901.

Comment: That worked, but I had to change the SQL table definitions to CHARs and in the object as well, which then STRTOTIME then seems to be able to parse. When I had it as a date object it still wasn't working. Thanks!