# Browsers and Jquery

Tags: jquery, browser

Is it possible for a browser to disable J QUERY. I have an issue where the user is submitting details in a form, it is saving to the database but when it submit the email, the dates set to the details dates ie Decemeber 31, 1969. Is it possible this is a browser issue. I did the same test and did not encounter this issue.

If so, how can i use my code to prevent this from happening?

Comment: It seems to be the first date of your DB system to me (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644888/only-some-dates-from-sql-select-being-set-to-0-or-1969-12-31-unix-timesta). Like if the user didn't sent any date at all.

Comment: _"Is it possible for a browser to disable J QUERY"_ Yes, all browsers can disable JavaScript and thus jQuery.

Comment: @j08691 I can't disable JavaScript on my Nintendo DS browser... :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - dang, but I can on my [WebTV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSN_TV) ;)

Answer (score 1):

That means that the date is being submitted in a format that the server is not understanding.

[image: xkcd]
> [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1179/)

The solution is to better coordinate your browser and server. Not ask questions like whether the browser is capable of disabling arbitrary pieces of code...